# BEAST some misunderstandings

Tags: tls, beast

I was reading the *[Here Come The ⊕ Ninjas](http://www.hit.bme.hu/~buttyan/courses/EIT-SEC/abib/04-TLS/BEAST.pdf)* document about the BEAST attack discovered by Thai Duong & Juliano Rizzo. There are two points I cannot understand.

At the section *5 - Application: Decrypting HTTPS Requests*, they explain step by step to makes this attack possible.

I will be focus on Step 3 and Step 4:
*(Reproduced as plain text here. A nicer [LaTeX rendering is on page 7 of the paper.](http://www.hit.bme.hu/~buttyan/courses/EIT-SEC/abib/04-TLS/BEAST.pdf#page=7))*

**Step 3**

> Let IV be the last ciphertext block that Mallory captures, e.g., IV is
>   Cn after step 2. Mallory computes Pi = IV XOR C2 XOR Pguess, where Pguess =
>   P/1.1\r\nW[i]. Mallory appends Pi to the existing request, e.g.,
>   Pi is appended to the request body (this is the last assumption.)
>   Alice’s browser would compute Ci  Ek(IV XOR Pi) and send Ci to server.

**Step 4**

> Mallory captures Ci. If Ci = C3, he knows that X is equal to W[i].
>   Otherwise he increases i and goes back to step 3.

Meaning that Mallory captures `C1` and compares the encrypted block `C1` = `C3`? Because IV is used to be XOR with `P1` so why do they speak about `Ci` like it can be `C1`, `C2`, `C3` .. `Cn` when it can only be `C1`?

In fact this reflexion comes from this :

*`Pi` is appended to the request body* -> the request body of an HTTP request? There is no sense to put this in the request body! Meaning IV is only use with the `P1` block.

So what's the point of putting `Pi` in the request body ?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes Pi is appended** to the body; (re)read the paragraph labelled **Blockwise Privilege** at the top of the page. Remember HTTP and thus HTTPS is a stream protocol; if you make a request to upload say 100 gigabytes uncompressed video you probably won't do it in a single step. To restate a little more finely:

- Step 1 Mallory's code causes something in Alice's browser to open a connection and **begin** a request. It formats the HTTP request header plus the **initial part** of the body (which actually might be empty), plus an HMAC and padding not relevant to the attack, forming **the first data record** blocked as `P1 .. Pn`, encrypts those to `C1 .. n`, and sends those blocks. For the example, block `P3` (encrypted to `C3`) contains a known value except one byte of cookie Mallory wants to guess.
- Step 2 Mallory captures `C1 .. Cn`
- Step 3A Mallory forms `Pi = (IV=Cn) xor C2 xor Pguess` (a guessed value for P3).
- Step 3B Mallory's code tells the something `Pi` is the **next block** of the request body. It therefore creates **a second data record** beginning with `Pi` (or if you prefer, `P2001` to mean the first block of the second record) plus other stuff we don't care about, encrypts it using `IV` (or `IV2` for second record) = `Cn`, producing `Ci .. ignored` (or `C2001 .. C200x`). Mallory captures these.

  **If** `Pguess` was correct (`Pguess = P3`) **then** 
  the block `Ci/C2001` encrypted from `Cn xor (Cn xor C2 xor Pguess=P3)`
  is the same as the block `C3` encrypted from `C2 xor P3`.

However, unless you have really old (and probably horribly unsafe) systems, you can no longer exploit BEAST, because practically everybody has implemented data fragmentation to block it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15224909/jsse-wrap-creates-two-tls-packets-requiring-two-unwraps-why/15225921#15225921 .

(PS: That document is PDF, not LaTeX. But it makes no difference to the meaning.)